# Question about ていくand 意志 (and side question about と usage with verbs)

Tags: grammar

I was reading this definition of ぶつかる on weblio.

> 〔動詞の「ぶつかる」は助詞の違いによって使い分けがある。「 A が B にぶつかる」（ A に意志・責任がある）の型は，「 A が B にぶつかった」（ A に責任がある）とも「 A が B にぶつかっていく」（意志的）とも言える。「 A が B とぶつかる」（ A に責任ある場合と，単に事実を言う場合）の型は，「 A が B とぶつかった」（単に事実を言う）は言えるが，「 A が B とぶつかっていく」（意志的）とは言えない。「 A と B （と）がぶつかる」の型は，単に事実を言う〕

I noticed the versions with ていく had 意志的 written next to them and I'm wondering, does ていく express some kind of intention? It says that the plain dictionary form merely indicates that the action happened, but I thought ていく was capable of that too? I know it can indicate intention with something like これからも勉強していく but I thought this was just one meaning, and that ぶつかっていく was indicating the direction of the action.

Also was curious about と being used with ぶつかる to 'plainly state a fact'. Is that a thing? I have wondered in the past about why と can replace some other particles (と話す seems obvious, 'speak with' rather than 'speak to' (に話す) but となる and になる elude me, but I once heard となる is used more formally and with abstract things)